# passing a variable by value using php

Tags: php

can any one please tell me how to pass a variable as/by value?
what i did a mistake on the below code, its shows an parse error

```
$a = &$$b
```

Comment: $a = '&$$b'; ? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might be a little hard to follow, your code is perfectly valid and is doing what you want it to do:

```
$b = 'test';
$test = 100;
$a = &$$b;
echo $a; // displays 100
```

You are likely getting an error because $b is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Passing by value is the normal behavior of PHP. So when you just write `$a = $b` the value of `$b` will be assigned to `$a`.

What you wrote is a reference assignment, declaring `$a` to be a reference to the variable that is identified by the value of `$b` (see [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Pass by value?

Internally, php always passes by reference. Only when you assign or change the values do php allocate new memory.

For example:

```
$a = 5;
$b = $a; // this points to the same memory location as a
$a = 2; // now b still points to the same memory location which has 5, but now $a points to a new location with a value of 2
```

So there is really no need to pass by reference/value. You only need to add the reference indicator (&) when you require that php to assign values to the same memory location and not allocate new memory.